# I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:185] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, voila

I'm trying to run a voila notebook on my local machine it gives me the error above although I developed the code on Google Colab and works well even in jupyter notebook the code running without problems the only problem is when I render the code using /voila/render the  code not working [Code Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7rnP.png)

Comment: post the error as text